# Compile protobuf with Xcode 5 using CocoaPods

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, protocol-buffers

I am trying to add GoogleProtobuf (2.5.0) to my application.  From what I have read, the best way is to use CocoaPods.  So I went through a tutorial for getting started with CocoaPods.  I got all the way to where I ran pod install in my project folder and it created the project workspace.  I open the project workspace and try to clean/build and I receive the following error:

[image]

I'm a newb at this.  Does this mean anything to anyone?

**Wow!  That's a little picture.**

Let me see if I can copy the info in:

```
Resolving target dependencies
Pods was rejected as an implicit dependency for 'libPods.a' because its architectures 'arm64' didn't contain all required architectures 'armv7'
Write auxiliary files

Ld /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-ggwchkzudvcbibdmaknlspphbkbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Demo.app/Demo normal armv7
    cd "/Users/pdl/Development/Application-Demos/iPhone_Demos/Demo"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=7.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS7.1.sdk -L/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-ggwchkzudvcbibdmaknlspphbkbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -L/Library/FlurryAnalytics/Flurry_iPhone_SDK_viPhone_4/Flurry-iOS-4.3.1/Flurry -F/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-ggwchkzudvcbibdmaknlspphbkbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Library/OpenCV -F/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/QlmMobileDeviceSample-cuzqlikbteeedbeaonfqofugyyql/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos -F/Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Dummy-iOS-gumpxuupcpajbvamflgypgfwjshp/Build/Products/Release-iphoneuniversal -filelist /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-ggwchkzudvcbibdmaknlspphbkbr/Build/Intermediates/Demo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Demo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Demo.LinkFileList -dead_strip -ObjC -lstdc++ -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=7.0 -framework Dummy-iOS-1.1.0 -lFlurry_4.3.1 -framework QlmLicenseMobile -lc++ -framework opencv2 -framework AdSupport -lz -lxml2.2 -framework Security -framework SystemConfiguration -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreGraphics -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -lPods -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-ggwchkzudvcbibdmaknlspphbkbr/Build/Intermediates/Demo.build/Debug-iphoneos/Demo.build/Objects-normal/armv7/Demo_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/pdl/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Demo-ggwchkzudvcbibdmaknlspphbkbr/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Demo.app/Demo

ld: library not found for -lPods
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

My Podfile contains this:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'
pod 'GoogleProtobuf', '~> 2.5.0'
```

When I ran the install, this is the output:

```
pdl-mbp:Demo pdl$ pod install
Analyzing dependencies

CocoaPods 0.32.1 is available.

Downloading dependencies
Installing GoogleProtobuf (2.5.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project

[!] From now on use `Demo.xcworkspace`.
[deprecated] I18n.enforce_available_locales will default to true in the future. If you really want to skip validation of your locale you can set I18n.enforce_available_locales = false to avoid this message.

[!] The target `Demo [Debug]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `Demo [Debug - Release]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.

[!] The target `Demo [Debug - Release - Ad Hoc Distribution]` overrides the `OTHER_LDFLAGS` build setting defined in `Pods/Pods.xcconfig'.
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
pdl-mbp:Demo pdl$
```

Comment: I followed the instructions here to no avail:
  http://www.mobinett.com/2013/09/20/ios-7-xcode-5-project-build-settings-for-architectures-and-arm64-support/

Comment: I found more information at this SO Question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263539/cocoa-pods-error-ld-library-not-found-for-lpods

Comment: That question led me to this page:  https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/pull/1352

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so I found s lot of information at the two links provided in my last two comments.  Especially   [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21264621/1) to the SO Question.

My issue ended up being that my Pods Valid Architectures had to be the same as the Valid Architectures are in my project.

I spent all day on this and the minute I posted the question, I found an answer that helped me figure out my problem.

I hope this helps somebody else!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Check all libraries of projects. If you see anyone missing (red color) , update it specifically. Or you can thoroughly update all libraries with command "pod update" with going into the projects directory. It solved my problem.